# Cannot start Cutegram

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, package-management, aptitude

I installed Cutegram
When I start it I get

```
./cutegram: error whiel loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I use Debian 9. I tried `apt-get install libgstreamer-0.10` but it can't find any package.
Also I found a post where someone is typing about new version of Cutegram https://github.com/Aseman-Land/Cutegram/issues/296 but I can't find it anywhere to download

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong package name. The correct package would be `libgstreamer0.10-0`.

You can find the correct package name of something by using `apt-cache search <term>`.

For example:

```
$ apt-cache search libgstreamer
libgstreamer-interfaces-perl - Perl interface to the GStreamer Interfaces library
libgstreamer-ocaml - OCaml interface to the gstreamer library -- runtime files
libgstreamer-ocaml-dev - OCaml interface to the gstreamer library -- development files
libgstreamer-perl - Perl interface to the GStreamer media processing framework
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 - GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "base" set
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 - GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "base" set
libgstreamer0.10-0 - Core GStreamer libraries and elements
libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg - Core GStreamer libraries and elements
libgstreamer0.10-dev - GStreamer core development files
libgstreamer1.0-0 - Core GStreamer libraries and elements
libgstreamer1.0-0-dbg - Core GStreamer libraries and elements
libgstreamer1.0-dev - GStreamer core development files
libgstreamerd-3-0 - GStreamer media framework - D bindings
libgstreamerd-3-dev - GStreamer media framework - development files for D
libgstreamermm-1.0-1 - C++ wrapper library for GStreamer (shared libraries)
libgstreamermm-1.0-dev - C++ wrapper library for GStreamer (development files)
libgstreamermm-1.0-doc - C++ wrapper library for GStreamer (documentation)
```